# Android Studio: Execution failed for task: unable to merge dex

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just add a module to my android project. Android Studio builds the project correctly, but when I attempt to launch the app, I getting this error.

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

My project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:0.4.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.apollographql.android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yamblet.smartliving"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':openpayandroid')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:0.4.4'
    implementation "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-android-support:0.4.4"
    implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-http-cache:0.4.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.master.android:permissionhelper:1.1'
    implementation 'com.iamhabib:easy-preference:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:2.0.2'

    //RETROFIT
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    //JSON PARSING
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.master.android:permissionhelper:1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"


}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Module gradle that I added

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile files('libs/devicecollector-sdk-2.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.17.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.17.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.17.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/junit-4.10.jar')
}
```

I clean and rebuild the project but, the error persists in the build process. Also I add `multiDexEnabled true` but didnt work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is instant run enabled? Try turning that off if so.

Comment: Yes, it was enabled. I just turned it off, but the error persits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I executed this gradle, and it works only problem I can see here is `implementation project(':openpayandroid')`, i didn't included it as its your private library, but on my understanding openpayandroid is also including some same dependencies which is causing the problem, so solution can be to exclude that group from it, eg `implementation project(':openpayandroid')
{
exclude group 'the dex error causing lib group'
}`
if above does'nt work try this
 in your project build.gradle try use same version of all the groups e.g.

```
if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0" // your version
            }
```

I think this might help but if this doesn't work try to check which file is responsible for this dex error and edit your question

One more thing you have include permission helper twice, remove (but it might not be the problem )

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `multiDexEnabled true` ie. multidex enabled in your app gradle under android section

Answer (score 1):

In build.gradle   in default config use
     **multiDexEnabled true** 
and add dependency like **compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'**
and extend your application file with **MultidexApplication** and rebuild your project. This will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you update the dependencies recently try this answer

Just clean the project & re-build the project

```
Build -> Clean project 
Build -> Rebuild project
```